# Linking to the image in Google Drive Issue

Tags: google-docs

I tried to use the format

```
http://googledrive.com/host/<folderID>/<filename>
```

and I've already set both image folder and asset to "Public on the web". However, when I tried calling the url using incognito mode, it just redirect me to sign-in page. Could anyone point me out of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you right-click the file you want to share, there is a "Get Link" choice.

Comment: Yes, but I prefer calling directly from its filename.